# Using PHP/MySQL with Google Maps (adding current position marker)

Tags: php, mysql, google-maps

Hello in my tries to make an app using google maps API
(with this tutorial https://developers.google.com/maps/articles/phpsqlajax_v3 ) . I have a question that I cant solve. 
How can I place a marker on this map to show the current location?
 I tried changing `"http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"` but nothing changes.
I also tried to use the HTML geolocation but no luck. I read from here [link](http://www.paulund.co.uk/how-to-use-geolocation-api-with-google-maps)
but still no luck. Whats is the proper way to do this? I can submit the code I have till now
if it's needed.

```
    <!DOCTYPE html >
  <head>
  <meta http-equiv="Cache-Control" content="no-cache, no-store, must-revalidate" />
<meta http-equiv="Pragma" content="no-cache" />
<meta http-equiv="Expires" content="0" />
    <meta name="viewport" content="initial-scale=1.0, user-scalable=no" />
    <meta http-equiv="content-type" content="text/html; charset=UTF-8"/>
    <title>PHP/MySQL & Google Maps Example</title>
    <script type="text/javascript" src="http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/js?sensor=true"></script>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    //<![CDATA[

    var customIcons = {
      restaurant: {
        icon: 'green-cross.png'
      },
      bar: {
        icon: 'http://labs.google.com/ridefinder/images/mm_20_red.png'
      }
    };

function get_location() {
  navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition(show_map);
}
    function load() {
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map"), {
        center: new google.maps.LatLng(39.640793 , 22.416093),
        zoom: 13,
        mapTypeId: 'roadmap'
      });
      var infoWindow = new google.maps.InfoWindow;



      // Change this depending on the name of your PHP file
      downloadUrl("phpsqlajax_genxml.php", function(data) {
        var xml = data.responseXML;
        var markers = xml.documentElement.getElementsByTagName("marker");
        for (var i = 0; i < markers.length; i++) {
          var name = markers[i].getAttribute("name");
          var address = markers[i].getAttribute("address");
          var type = markers[i].getAttribute("type");
          var point = new google.maps.LatLng(
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lat")),
              parseFloat(markers[i].getAttribute("lng")));
          var html = "<b>" + name + "</b> <br/>" + address;
          var icon = customIcons[type] || {};
          var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
            map: map,
            position: point,
            icon: icon.icon
          });
          bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html);
        }
      });
    }

    function bindInfoWindow(marker, map, infoWindow, html) {
      google.maps.event.addListener(marker, 'click', function() {
        infoWindow.setContent(html);
        infoWindow.open(map, marker);
      });
    }

    function downloadUrl(url, callback) {
      var request = window.ActiveXObject ?
          new ActiveXObject('Microsoft.XMLHTTP') :
          new XMLHttpRequest;

      request.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (request.readyState == 4) {
          request.onreadystatechange = doNothing;
          callback(request, request.status);
        }
      };

      request.open('GET', url, true);
      request.send(null);
    }

    function doNothing() {}


    //]]>

  </script>

  </head>

  <body onload="load()">
    <div id="map" style="width: 1920px; height: 1080px"></div>
  </body>

</html>
```

Comment: The API include only informs Google that you are using a sensor, changing that doesn't do anything.  We can't help you without your code. [geolocation example from the documentation](https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/map-geolocation)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simplest example I can come up with to place a marker using html5 geolocation:

```
function initialize() {

  if (navigator.geolocation)
  {
      var position = navigator.geolocation.getCurrentPosition();
      yourLat = position.coords.latitude;
      yourLng = position.coords.longitude;
      var myLatlng = new google.maps.LatLng(yourLat, yourLng);
      var mapOptions = {
        zoom: 4,
        center: myLatlng
      }
      var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById('your-map-canvas'), mapOptions);

      var marker = new google.maps.Marker({
          position: myLatlng,
          map: map,
          title: 'Hello World!'
      });
  }
}

google.maps.event.addDomListener(window, 'load', initialize);
```

Adapted from: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/examples/marker-simple and  http://www.w3schools.com/html/html5_geolocation.asp.